# Firefox 89 Hardware Acceleration on Ubuntu 21.04 with Nvidia 460 drivers

Tags: drivers, nvidia, firefox

I can't seem to get Hardware Acceleration for Firefox working correctly with the closed source Nvidia 460 drivers.

Playing video (ie youtube) stutters often with dropped frames. I have an i7 6700k with a Nvidia 1070 GPU.

If I disable Hardware Acceleration entirely in Firefox, I don't experience these performance issues.

Has anyone come across this issue before?